# How to decompress a .bz2 file

Tags: linux, compression, bzip2

I have a file as: `filename.bz2` I need to decompress.

I have tried the command: `tar xvjf filename.tar.bz2`, but it didn't work as the file is not a `tar` file.

How do I decompress this file?

Answer (score 702, accepted):

Try the following:

```
bzip2 -d filename.bz2
```

Note, that this command will not preserve original archive file.

To preserve the original archive, add the `-k` option:

```
bzip2 -dk filename.bz2
```

Comment: You can also use bunzip2, which defaults to using the -d (uncompress) option.

Comment: @LewisDiamond I ran `bzip2 -d vim-8.0.tar.bz2`, that results `vim-8.0.tar`. I couldn't enter this.

Comment: @alhelal that's because it's a .tar.bz2 file. You unzipped the tarball, you're left with the unzipped tarbal. Extract it with `tar -x vim-8.0.tar`. Originally you could have used `tar -xjvf vim-8.0.tar.bz2`.

Comment: A slight correction to Lewis's comment, tar also needs -f (at least on Raspbian Wheezy) as follows `tar -xf vim-8.0.tar`

Answer (score 77):

To explain a bit further, a single file can be compressed with `bzip2` thus:

`bzip2 myfile.txt`

`tar` is only required when compressing multiple files:

`tar cvjf myfile.tar.bz *.txt`

Hence, when uncompressing a `.bz2` file use `bunzip`, when uncompressing a `tar.bz2` file use `tar xjvf`.

Comment: Excellent advice about the xjvf, just saved me. Thanks!

Comment: You can just use `tar xjf filename.tar.bz2`. The `v` just adds verbose output. Keep your terminal clean! I also had problems running `tar -xjf`, so be sure to try running it sans the `-`

Comment: `tar xf` should be sufficient with the BSD variant — the `j` flag is only used when compressing

Answer (score 27):

Use the `bunzip2` (or `bzip2 -d`) command to decompress the file. For more information see this [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bzip&sektion=&n=1),

Comment: Link is broken Levon

Answer (score 22):

`bzip2` is mono-threaded, which means it will take a long time to decompress a large file.

To decompress a `.bz2` file multithreadedly, you can use the free, open source program  [`lbzip2`](http://lbzip2.org/):

```
sudo apt-get install lbzip2
lbzip2 -d my_file.bz2
```

`-d` indicates you wish to decompress the file. It would automatically determine how many threads it will use. To specify the exact number of threads you want to use, use the `-n` parameter, e.g.:

```
lbzip2 -d -n 32 my_file.bz2
```

---

A few more useful commands with `lbzip2`:

To compress a file with a progress bar:

```
pv adb_int.tar | lbzip2 > adb_int.tar.bz2
```

Requirements for the progress bar:

```
sudo apt-get install -y pv
```

To compress a folder:

```
tar -c -I lbzip2 -f file.tar.bz2 folder_name
```

To uncompress a folder:

```
 tar -I lbzip2 -xvf file.tar.bz2
```

Parameters:

```
-I, --use-compress-program PROG
      filter through PROG (must accept -d)
-x, --extract, --get
      extract files from an archive
-v, --verbose
      verbosely list files processed
-f, --file ARCHIVE
      use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

---

Some alternatives to decompress a `.bz2` file multithreadedly:

[`pbzip2`](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/):

```
sudo apt-get install pbzip2
pbzip2 -d my_file.bz2
```

[`mpibzip2`](http://compression.ca/mpibzip2): designed to be used on on cluster machines.

---

If you need some large `.bz2` files to experiment with: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/mirrors.html

For example (a 14 GB `.bz2` file, 200 GB uncompressed):

```
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.your.org/wikidatawiki/20170120/wikidatawiki-20170120-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2 
lbzip2 -d -n 32 wikidatawiki-20170120-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2
```

http://vbtechsupport.com/1614/ did the benchmark:

[image]

---

For further information regarding the parameters for `lbzip2`: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=lbzip2+-d+-n+32+my_file.bz2 :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
bzip2 -dc my_file.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
```

worked for me on cygwin

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a few sentences to your answer to explain what it does.

Comment: @fixer1234 '-c' option copies the decompressed output to STDOUT which is then piped to tar utility and presented as filename using '-' so you can simplify it as: 
`bzip2 -d my_file.tar.bz2 ; tar xvf my_file.tar`

Comment: I believe even this should work `bzip2 -dc my_file.tar.bz2 | tar xv` i.e. no need to use -f option and corresponding '-' sign after it because tar can directly read the from STDOUT through the pipe operator. Also, feel free to drop -v option if you don't want to list files being processed.

Comment: This doesn't help, since the original poster already mentioned that it's not a `tar` archive.

Answer (score -6):

1. Go to https://cloudconvert.com.
2. Upload the file.
3. Convert it into a .tar file.
4. Download it.
5. Extract it from there, in your terminal.

Comment: Isn't suitable for really large files!

Comment: We're superusers. We want a terminal-based solution.

Comment: @Mr. de Santos ... and thereby giving up control over your data. You can not be serious.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thank you. We don't need all of our solutions to be terminal-based and in my case, I don't care if I send my particular bz2 file to a service for conversion.